# Is covariance of two random variables from the same distribution the same as the variance of this distribution?

Tags: variance, covariance

Sorry that this might be a very simple question, but I got confused: say we have a Binomial distribution $Bin(n, p)$, and two random variables, $X$ and $Y$, drawn from it.

Is the covariance between $X$ and $Y$ as simple as $np(1-p)$ (i.e. the variance of this Binomial distribution)?

Comment: You need to specify the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$; saying both $X$ and $Y$ is binomial is not enough. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then covariance is zero of course.

Comment: If X = Y a.s., then yes.

Comment: Or perhaps you meant the [Multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) with $k=2$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, thanks. I was referring two random variables drawn from the same distribution (parametrized by the same $p$), so I think they are dependent in the sense that they are from the same distribution? Or are they effectively the same random variable...?

Comment: If you only say that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution, that doesn't imply $X=Y$ with probability one. So no, we cannot say they are the same.

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do, but the problem is that $E[X \cdot Y]$ is only the same as $E[X \cdot X]$ if $X=Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the simple experiment of rolling two fair six-sided dice. The outcomes on the two dice may reasonably be taken to be independent.

Let's call it a success if a die shows 5 or 6 and a failure otherwise. That is, let X and Y be 1 if the first and second die (respectively) show a 5 or 6 and 0 otherwise, so that they form an independent, identically distributed pair of Bernoulli random variables (i.e. just as in your question, but for the special case n=1)

While their distribution is the same, $\text{cov}(X,Y) = 0$ (indeed, clearly they're independent).

[You can easily write their joint distribution and explicitly compute their covariance if you wish.]

Answer (score 3):

The covariance of two random variables with the identical *variance* $\sigma^2$ (note, *no* requirement that the *distributions* be identical or that they be binomial, etc) always has value in the interval $[-\sigma^2, \sigma^2]$. So, Yes, the covariance *can* have value $\sigma^2$ but this happens only when the random variables are *equal*, that is, $X$ always has the same value as $Y$ for every possible outcome of the experiment.